# OpenCV Mat to alglib real 2d Array conversion

Tags: c++, opencv, data-conversion, mat, alglib

How to convert Opencv Mat to Alglib real 2D array?

Here is an example where I am stucked

```
Mat Col(28539,97,CV_32F);
```

I want to convert this `Mat` to alglib `real_2d_array` for training a classifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Mat Col(28539, 97, CV_32F);
```

is a OpenCV bi-dimensional (28539 rows, 97 columns) dense floating-point (CV_32F = float) array.

The alglib almost-equivalent [datatype](http://www.alglib.net/translator/man/manual.cpp.html#gs_datatypes) is

```
// bi-dimensional real (double precision) array
real_2d_array matrix;
```

The data layout in `Mat` is compatible with `real_2d_array` (and the majority of dense array types from other toolkits and SDKs).

A simple way to convert is:

```
const int rows(28539);
const int columns(97);

matrix.setlength(rows, columns);

for (int i(0); i < rows; ++i)
  for (int j(0); j < columns; ++j)
    matrix(i, j) = Col.at<float>(i, j);
```

[`Mat::at`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-at) returns a reference to the specified array element.

EDIT

From the [reference manual](http://www.alglib.net/translator/man/manual.cpp.html#unit_dforest):

```
void alglib::dfbuildrandomdecisionforest(
    real_2d_array xy,
    ae_int_t npoints,
    ae_int_t nvars,
    ae_int_t nclasses,
    ae_int_t ntrees,
    double r,
    ae_int_t& info,
    decisionforest& df,
    dfreport& rep);
```

- `xy` is the training set (lines corresponding to sample components and columns corresponding to variables).

  For a classification task the first `nvars` of the columns contain independent variables. The **last** column will contain the class number (from 0 to `nclasses-1`). Fractional values are rounded to the nearest integer.
- `npoints` is the training set size (`>=1`).
- `nvars` is the number of independent variables (`>=1`).
- `nclasses` must be >1 for classification.
- `ntrees` is the number of trees in a forest (`>=1`).
- `r` is the percent of a training set used to build individual trees (`0 < R <= 1`).

The remaining parameters are output parameters. In case of problems you should check `info`:

- `info` return code:

  - -2, if there is a point with class number outside of `[0..nclasses-1]`.
  - -1, if incorrect parameters was passed (`npoints<1`, `nvars<1`, `nclasses<1`, `ntrees<1`, `r<=0` or `r>1`).
  - 1, if task has been solved.

Comment: Thanks manlio for your reply. I already did the same way. While other parameters i set are as alglib::dfbuildrandomdecisionforest(matrix, 28539, 96,7, 80, 0.66, info, df, rep); but still the model is not built. I also checked data contained in matrix which is also correct. Can you plz suggest what I am doing wrong(Like passing parameter to the random forest)

Comment: Have you checked the value of the `info` output parameter? The return code should be 1. Also the last column of `matrix` must contain the class number (from 0 to 6 in your case).

Comment: I checked output of info and it is -1 which means there is some problem with parameters. Let me tell you some detail....matrix contains training data and last column is class label. Other parameters are as alglib::dfbuildrandomdecisionforest(matrix, 28539, 96,7, 80, 0.66, info, df, rep);

Comment: total classes I am using are 7(7 parts of face i.e.nose,mouth,hair etc)